# What is the absolute value of the bottom of the conduction band / top of the valance band of Silicon?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I want to know the absolute values of the bottom/top of the conduction/valence band of Silicon.
I looked for it, only to find a bandgap of ~1.1 eV. Is there any literature or experimental data on it? I'm not interested in answers saying "those values are not important."

Comment: The values are important, and well known. See https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1663501 for example.

Comment: These values are relative. And nothing changes if you do add a constant (with a vacuum level) .

Answer (score 1):

You can find this by looking up the [electron affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity#%22Electron_affinity%22_as_defined_in_solid_state_physics) $E_{ea}$ of silicon. This is the energy difference between a state at the lower edge of the conduction band and the vacuum energy (the energy of a stationary free electron at the surface of the material).

Taking the vacuum energy as a reference, the conduction band edge energy $E_C$ is
$$E_C = -E_{ea}$$

From this and the band gap energy you can calculate the energy of the top of the valence band.

The electron affinity of silicon is about 4.05 eV.

Comment: Guao! That's what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot!